# Копирование в буфер из переменной

Tags: reactjs, get, copy

У меня следующая проблема:
Мне нужно при нажатии на кнопку, отправить запрос на сервер, дождаться ответа, и ответ уже как строку скопировать в буфер обмена (в ответе придёт url).

я сделал это с помощью

```
<CopyToClipboard onCopy={onClick} text={copy} > Кнопка </CopyToClipboard>
```

но есть проблема, когда я нажимаю кнопку - идёт запрос, и переменная copy не дожидается ответа.
То есть кнопка начинает работать только со 2-го нажатия

Сталкивался кто с подобной проблемой, и как можно решить эту задачу?

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Нашёл решение с помощью npm пакета use-clipboard-copy

ссылка: https://www.npmjs.com/package/use-clipboard-copy

работает на подобии хука, и с ней можно сделать то что я писал выше в 1 клик.

Answer (score 1):

```
.then( data => navigator.clipboard.writeText( data.url))
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]